# determining range of values of TypedArray item

Tags: javascript, web-frontend

According to [the documentation on the Uint8ClampedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray),

> The Uint8ClampedArray typed array represents an array of 8-bit unsigned integers clamped to 0-255; if you specified a value that is out of the range of [0,255], 0 or 255 will be set instead.

Other [TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray)s function similarly. Given any typed array amongst the types listed, is there a way to programmatically derive the max/min value possible to store therein?

Something along the lines of:

```
Uint8ClampedArray().maxItemValue // returns 255
```

Comment: [`BYTES_PER_ELEMENT`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/BYTES_PER_ELEMENT) might help, but you still need to distinguish signed from unsigned types.

Comment: yeah, I saw that too... it might ultimately be most efficient to just do a switch statement on the name property, but it'd be nice not to have to do that.

Comment: Why on the `.name` property? You can switch on the functions themselves if you want.

Comment: Do you want the max of **every** type (even floats)? Do you want the min as well (for signed types)?

Comment: every type that a TypedArray might hold, min and max, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the following:

```
function maxElementValue(arr) {
    const c = arr.constructor;
    const test = c.of(-1.5)[0];
    if (test > 0) // unsigned integers
        return test;
    //  return 0xFFFFFFFF >>> (32 - 8 * c.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
    //  return Math.pow(2, 8 * c.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT) - 1;
    if (test == -1) // signed integers
        return 0x7FFFFFFF >>> (32 - 8 * c.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
    //  return Math.pow(2, 8 * c.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT - 1) - 1;
    if (test == 0) // clamped
        return 0xFF; // there's only one of these
    if (test == -1.5)
        throw new TypeError("floats are not supported");
    throw new TypeError("weirdly behaving typed array");
}
```

Comment: nice! this seems like it works as expected. I *think* I can figure out the minimum value part on my own.